# How to hide the selection rectangle/dotted lines in a Qt QListView or QListWidget?

Tags: qt, selection, paint

In my interface, I would like to not display the dotted lines/rectangle around the currently selected item.

I read online that there was no way to do this with stylesheets, and the best way was to create a new class to override the paint method, as suggested in [this link](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/10099-How-to-remove-the-dotted-rectangle-of-selection).

However, it would be great to do without having to create a whole other class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out in many cases it **is** possible, by simply setting `QListWidget::focusPolicy` to `NoFocus`, as suggested [here](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/33362-Removing-a-dotted-selection-line-thing-in-a-QListWidget).